# Athena query successful but returns all blank field values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a parquet file in a bucket on AWS. I can look at the file in an online parquet viewer and it looks correct. And I can go to S3 and look at it with "Query with S3 Select" there it looks fine as well. I have a glue catalog parquet table defined that points to this location. But when I query it in Athena, the query is successful and he field names appear in the headers, but all fields are blank. I know it is accessing the correct file, as if I change the # of records in the file, the Athena query reflects that as it returns the # of records I have in there, but still all fields are blank. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Is the data partitioned? Has a Glue crawler crawled the underlying data objects?

Comment: Any chance you could share a sample .parquet file?